# ADB - Open Contact Details by Phone Number

Tags: android, adb, contacts

I am trying to open the contact details for an Android phone contact by their phone number in ADB.

The command

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW content://contacts/people/`

will open the contacts app, while

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW content://contacts/people/1`

will open up the contact details for the contact with CONTACT_ID equal to 1.  I essentially want to do this same thing, only by passing in the contact's phone number, and not the contact ID.  I suppose an error should be thrown, or the command should do nothing, if no contact exists with the given phone number.

I ask this because I am running certain adb commands on a KitKat device from an external testing suite, and do not have access to the Android API.

Is what I'm trying to do here even possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `content://contacts` provider has been deprecated for awhile. You should be using `content://com.android.contacts` instead.

To find the proper `contact_id` to `android.intent.action.VIEW` for your phone number do `adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/data/phones/filter/<phone number> --projection contact_id`

For more consistent results make sure to use phone number in normalized [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) format.

Comment: While this technically works, the results are very inconsistent with the data on my phone.  For example, running `content query --uri content://contacts/people/ --where 'number is not null' --projection _id` only returns 3 results, when I should be seeing at least 50.  Any ideas what could be happening here?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alex - how would I do that from adb exactly?